# QValueList reverse iterator

Tags: qt

How to make reverse looping for QValueList?

i found, thanks to all

```
QValueList<int> l;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) l.append(i);
QValueListIterator<int> it = l.end(); --it;
for (; it != l.end(); --it)
{
    qDebug(QString::number(*it));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is [change it to a QLinkedList](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/porting4.html)

As it happens, the linked article shows an example of reverse looping.